# Can matter and light exist without the free space absolute vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, vacuum, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

According to the standard model of particle physics, is matter and light possible to exist without the existence of the omnipresent vacuum?

By "vacuum" here I mean the ideal *perfect vacuum* thus [free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum) that can be characterized in Maxwell equations with two parameters, the electric permittivity $ε_{0}$ and magnetic  permeability $μ_{0}$ of *free space*.

Obviously, in Maxwell's theory the existence of the vacuum is a necessary condition for the EM force to exist thus also necessary for the creation of matter and light.

But what about the Standard Model of particle physics? How is this formulated and formally described and physically explained? Is the vacuum quantized and if yes does it have a separate unique possible yet unknown elementary particle consisting the ideal perfect free space vacuum?

All the above of course *assuming* that there is not really "nothing or perfect void" in our universe and there is always "something" instead of "nothing". Thus, even the ideal perfect *free space vacuum* is not nothing but rather something!

Thank you *in advance* for answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many questions contained in the post. I will try to answer some of them.

You can think of the *vacuum state* as furnishing the stage upon which the drama involving particles, waves, energy and matter is performed. The stage can exist without the play but the play cannot exist without the stage.

The standard model is the script for that play, and it says nothing about how the stage is constructed. Similarly, the stage does not describe the script.

Maxwell's equations describe only a part of the action on that stage; you cannot follow the plot of the play if you are only reading the portions of the script that have Maxwell's name in them.

Physicists know that there was a time long ago during the construction of the stage (early moments in the big bang) when the action on the stage was so violent as to bend the boards and toss the props about and rip holes in the backdrops. This means that the structure and shape of the stage was strongly affected by the nature of the script, but to this day no one knows how to revise the script (i.e., quantize the vacuum  and make the standard model *background-dependent*) so as to include the stage itself as a dynamical plot element or character in the unfolding drama.

Physicists also know that the thing we commonly refer to as "the vacuum" is *not* "nothing"; that it possess physical properties we can measure; and that it is not most assuredly *not* "empty".